# Потокобезопасный перебор коллекции

Tags: c#, многопоточность, коллекции

Подскажите, как можно реализовать коллекцию, реализующую INotifyCollectionChanged, и которую можно было бы потокобезопасно перебирать? Наследоваться от ConcurrentCollection не получится, т.к. не получится реализовать INotifyCollectionChanged.

Для потокобезопасного перебора я вижу следующие варианты:
1) Блокировать коллекцию на время обхода. Но, если обработка элемента занимает длительное время, этот вариант не подходит
2) Перед перебором коллекции блокировать доступ к ней на время создания её копии и перебирать уже копию. Но при частом переборе будет создаваться много мусора.

Если наследоваться от ObservableCollection, то получу весь необходимый функционал, вставив блокировку в методы, модифицирующие коллекцию, но не смогу переопределить GetEnumerator и скопировать в нем коллекцию для потокобезопасного обхода коллекции.

Единственный вариант - реализовать свою коллекцию с нуля?

Comment: `как можно реализовать коллекцию, реализующую INotifyCollectionChanged, и которую можно было бы потокобезопасно перебирать?` зачем? Почему нельзя скопировать начальную коллецию в, например, массив и перебирать сколько хочется?

Comment: ну и что вы подразумеваете под потокобезопасным перебором? Перебор, при котором коллекция меняется в другом потоке? Перебор несколькими потоками?

Comment: @tym32167 Да - в одном потоке объекты добавляются и удаляются из коллекции, в другом потоке идет перебор коллекции. Как безопасно скопировать, если копирование коллекции в массив - это не атомарная операция? Добавить открытое свойство SyncRoot и лочить его при каждом обращении к коллекции?

Comment: У меня были конфликты при переборе коллекции. Я проблему решал через исключение - и на повтор перебора. Но коллекция - чужак (список коннектов и курсоров СУБД). Для "своей" реализации - я советую правильно выбрать тип обвертки, например использовать очередь, с пометкой concurency. Для списка кажись нужно вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874317/thread-safe-listt-property

Comment: вы же понимаете, что коллекция, реализующая `INotifyCollectionChanged` скорее всего предназначена для однопоточного доступа, доступа только в UI потоке. То есть, если вы будете с этой коллекцией только через UI поток работать, то, используя диспетчер, вы легко можете скопировать коллекцию в массив - это будет потокобезопасно, так как будет выполнено все в одном потоке.

Comment: Судя по всему, вы что-то делаете не так, опишите, для чего вам это нужно!

Comment: @tym32167, согласен, если данные добавляются в другом потоке, то обновлять UI через привязки не получится, видимо нужно добавить к классу-коллекции метод, который вернет скопированную коллекцию

Comment: @Monomax Есть коллекция объектов, которая изменяется в фоновом потоке. Эта коллекция заполняет datagridview, объекты этой коллекции наносятся на карту и график, при изменении свойств объектов коллекции необходимо обновить таблицу, график, отображение на карте

Comment: Обычно используют разделение логики на отдельные слои. К примеру в WPF используют MVVM, который все разделяет на слои (Model-ViewModel-View), в Model делают всю логику работы например с базой, сайтом или еще чем, там используют потоки и др. В ViewModel реализуют только то, что требуется отобразить и то, как интерфейс будет взаимодействовать с моделью. То есть в моделе есть потокобезопасная коллекция и метод на изменение, в VM этот метод вызываем и все изменения записываем в обычную коллекцию внутри VM слоя, дальше View все это выводит. Интерфейсу не всегда нужна потокобезопасность, разделите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, можно поподробнее? Допустим в модели определена потокобезопасная коллекция, которая обновляется по таймеру в фоновом потоке. Данные из этой коллекции необходимо отобразить в UI. Во VM должна быть дублирующая коллекция? Как в таком случае организовать синхронизацию коллекции в M и VM, если они должны обновляться в разных потоках?

Comment: `Во VM должна быть дублирующая коллекция?` - не дублирующая, а та, которая будет отвечать исключительно за взаимодействие с View, то есть некая `ObservableCollection`, которая будет содержать к примеру только товары, доступные для покупки сегодня. Если у вас огромное кол-во объектов в базе, то не стоит их все выводить. `Синхронизация` - я обычно делаю в M событие, которое оповещает об изменении/добавление чего то нового и по нему в VM обновляю данные, в обратную сторону - делаю в M метод, который принимает объект и этот метод обновляет уже в базе или где то еще данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в моем случае - winform, коллекция наполняется объектами, полученными по сети от некоторого устройства, и все эти объекты необходимо отобразить на форме. Получается алгоритм такой - в фоновом потоке обновляется колекция - испускается событие, в UI потоке происходит обработка этого события и синхронизация observable- коллекции для обновления GUI?

Comment: Ну в WPF подобных приложениях я бы сделал так, да. То есть разделил бы логику работы с устройствами и логику отображения на разные слои (в WPF это MVVM). В WinForms как там положено, я честно, без понятия. Вроде там тоже используются подходы, называются MVP/MVC если память не изменяет.